# Exclude a column from a sql join query

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
select * 
from SMFeecollectionhdr coll
join SMFeecollectiondtl colldtl on colldtl.transid = coll.id 
join SMFeechallanhdr challan on challan.Id = colldtl.challanid
join SMPerioddtl period on period.Id = challan.perioddtlid
join SMCourse course on course.Id = challan.courseid
join SMSection section on section.Id = challan.sectionid
join SMStudentinfo std on std.Id = coll.studentid
where coll.entityid = 5030
```

I want exclude a column called `remarks` from my result. This column belongs to the table `SMCourse`.

What's the easiest way to do it? I have tried using "except" command but it doesn't seem to work or maybe I was using it wrongly.

Comment: can you provide your DB structure?

Comment: Simply select only the columns you want to be returned.

Comment: I need to include all columns except that one @jarlh. and there are a lot of columns, as you can see its pretty big join

Comment: That's still the way to do it. Besides https://dzone.com/articles/why-you-should-not-use-select-in-sql-query-1, https://tanelpoder.com/posts/reasons-why-select-star-is-bad-for-sql-performance/, https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/finding-code-smells-using-sql-prompt-asterisk-select-list etc

Comment: I agree with @jarlh, it's always a better practice to list all colums you need not just using *

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms